# Why doesn't this postDelayed run forever?

Tags: java, android, handler, postdelayed

This is my code, but in theory it should keep posting this log message every second until forever, but it doesn't. Any ideas? My goal is to have it run forever, but a while loop also doesn't work.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Blink extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blink);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            Log.d("AAA", "Test");
            }
        }, 1000);

    }

}
```

Comment: postDelayed only executes the runnable once after the given time (1 sec in your case)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add inside the runner:
`handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);`