# Vibrator App Android

Tags: android

I'm using my smartphone vibrate in my Android APP that I'm creating, I would like to know how I can do to give the Vibrate 3 vibrated followed by 100ms each.

```
// Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

// Vibrate for 100ms
vib.vibrate(100);
```

Comment: check out the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535733/display-data-after-every-10-seconds-in-android

and paste your vibrate code in run method

Comment: +1 for the title of the question

Comment: You guys are too bad ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard vibrate method with patterns parameter

```
public abstract void vibrate (long[] pattern, int repeat)
```

Pass in an array of ints that are the durations for which to turn on or off the vibrator in milliseconds. The first value indicates the number of milliseconds to wait before turning the vibrator on. The next value indicates the number of milliseconds for which to keep the vibrator on before turning it off. Subsequent values alternate between durations in milliseconds to turn the vibrator off or to turn the vibrator on.

To cause the pattern to repeat, pass the index into the pattern array at which to start the repeat, or -1 to disable repeating.

This method requires the caller to hold the permission VIBRATE.

Parameters
pattern an array of longs of times for which to turn the vibrator on or off.
repeat  the index into pattern at which to repeat, or -1 if you don't want to repeat.